# Installing apk on emulator in mac

Tags: android, macos, apk, adb, adt

I have followed following tut to install messaging-simulator.apk on my Nexus 7 emulator of adt sdk...

http://www.orhancanceylan.com/installing-and-testing-apk-files-to-the-android-emulator-on-mac/

But, after the device (virtual) is launched (which is annoyingly slow), no further action could be performed from terminal as it gets stuck or no progress is shown. (Basically, I am stuck after ./android command. Nothing can be entered in terminal after that. How do i resolve this?

[image: This is how it looks now at the end!, emulator not up!]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a ton to @Uriel Frankel. Yet, all those tips and tricks given by him did not work out for me due to low memory in my macbook.

So I have used Genymotion emulator(http://techapple.net/2014/05/3-best-android-emulators-for-mac-os-macbook-run-and-install-android-app-on-your-mac-os-x-macbook-airpro/) instead of default android emulator and successfully launched the app by installing it.

You can all try above solution first and if it did not work out, use Genymotion, it's cool :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't type a thing in the terminal - just open a new Terminal window and type it there.

A few tips that will speed up your emulator

1. Make your emulator as intel x86. and check Use host GPU
2. Install HAXM from the sdk manager
3. make the settings like this:
   [image]

I use mac to develop Android.

Comment: I have followed what you have mentioned. yet following is the result:* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

* daemon started successfully *

List of devices attached 

platform-tools smitha$ ./adb install /Users/smitha/Downloads/ADT/sdk/extras/google/simulators/messaging-simulator.apk

error: device not found
- waiting for device -
..

Comment: after the emulator finished start, write "adb kill-server" and after that "adb start-server"

Comment: its actually not starting properly! Very slow even after installing HAXM

Comment: Did you restart your mac after the haxm? and did you choose intel x86?

Comment: yep..i did. and suddenly now its showing - emulator-5555 offline and emulator is still not up!

Comment: alternatively if i run the command ./adb devices, its not showing uo list of devices

Comment: adb kill-server and adb start-server is also tried out!

Comment: When you created the emulator did you made it x86? did you checked use host gpu? if not edit your emulator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65943/discussion-between-smitha-and-uriel-frankel).

Comment: anybody facing the same issues?

Comment: I have pinged you further problems!

Comment: I have done all the changes as mentioned in your answer except I am using min target sdk android 5.0 API 21 as I have to test android auto! But result is still the same. Emulator is not up yet!

Comment: I tried using API 18 and this is the result:Starting emulator for AVD 'nexus'
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode; with a "abdroid" symbol up in emulator now but, no home page loads yet!